# Removing the title bar when using android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout without affecting rendering of sample layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to remove a title bar in an application I am currently working on which i wrote as an Empty Activity, but how ever I seem to get these errors

```
   Rendering Problems
   The following classes could not be instantiated:

   - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show     Exception, Clear Cache)
   - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show   Exception, Clear Cache)

   Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample  data when shown in the IDE

   Exception Details
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/design/R$styleable   at
   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:187)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>CoordinatorLayout.java:179)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
```

Here is my activity_main.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
         app:elevation="0dp">

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             android:id="@+id/toolbar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
             android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
             app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>


     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

     </LinearLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my styles.xml file is

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And finally my build.gradle for module.app is
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.captureinc.capture"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
    }
    dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
     }
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: activity_main.xml file is not correct

Comment: how? where should I change maybe?

Comment: I think the xml file you posted here is not correct, could you check you xml file in the code and the one which is present here

Comment: It should be correct now, it was just the indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the millionth time, you can't mix versions of support libraries like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'
```

Furthermore `design` depends on `appcompat-v7` and will pull it automatically so this will do just fine:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Eugen Pechanec , It is working and appreciate that